# What is the SQL/MP equivalent of CURRENT_DATE?

Tags: sql, hp-nonstop, sqlmp

SQL/MP is an SQL dialect used on proprietary HP NonStop SQL database systems which go back to the 1980ies... (Who has ever worked on a system that is as old as they are, huh? :))

SQL/MP is only somewhat ANSI compliant, for example `CURRENT_DATE` does not exist. I have however a hard time figuring out what functions *do* exist that can help me to get the current date in my queries.

Can anyone help me with this dinosaur of an SQL language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CURRENT or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP depending on the context.

The HP NonStop SQL/MP Reference Manual is excellent for this sort of thing - one advantage of using an older product, the documentation is good.

This is the url of [HP NonStopSQL/MP Reference Manual](http://www.nonstoptools.com/manuals/SqlMp-Reference.pdf) you can download it´s a pdf file.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while to dig through the 1000 page manual, but `CURRENT YEAR TO DAY` (which is the `CURRENT` command with some params) actually did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
CURRENT YEAR TO DAY
```

CURRENT is a function that returns the current local date, time, or both. You can find the options of parameters in the [HPE NonStopSQL/MP Reference Manual](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02132125-5.pdf) it´s most recent documentation that I know.